# How to address an Image in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

Sorry for the maybe stupid question. I start to get my head into Fabric.js, but it´s hard for me because of the documentation.

Please look at the code below:

```
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var iminst = new fabric.Image.fromURL ('./images/1stback.jpg', function(myimage){
     myimage.left=0;
     myimage.top=0;
     canvas.add(myimage);
  });

  iminst.set('angle', 45);
```

The image is loaded and shown, but how do I address it afterwards. 
I just get an Error 
"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'iminst.set('angle', 45)')"

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the basics. It seems like you haven't gone through the great tutorials available on the [Fabric site](http://fabricjs.com/articles/).

The simple code to solve your issue would be:

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var iminst;
    fabric.Image.fromURL ('./images/1stback.jpg', function(myimage){
        iminst=myimage;
        myimage.left=0;
        myimage.top=0;
        canvas.add(myimage);
        canvas.renderAll();
        test();
    });
    function test(){
        iminst.set('angle', 45); // you can refer it but not before the callback finished
    }
```

Hope it helps if you haven't yet figured out the answer by yourself... gl

Comment: Thanx, arty. Actually I was very close. I tried exactly your code, BUT had a a wrong declaration on the iminst Variable.

Comment: this is because you call iminst.set('angle', 45); before it actually assigned. It assigned only after the callback fired. i edited the problematic line in the code.